# Global section functor on cosheaves

Tags: homology-cohomology, sheaf-theory, derived-functors

Is the global section functor for cosheaves right exact?
For sheaves, this functor is left exact, thus giving rise to sheaf cohomology as a right derived functor, so I was wondering if this corresponded to cosheaf homology as a left derived functor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so the answer is yes. Follows from the gluing axiom.